# vb.net - hex, bitwise question

Tags: vb.net, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the lower 7 bits and 7-13 bits of two hex numbers.

Here is some example c code, just need this in vb.net:

```
serialBytes[2] = 0x64 & 0x7F; // Second byte holds the lower 7 bits of target.
serialBytes[3] = (0x64 >> 7) & 0x7F;   // Third data byte holds the bits 7-13 of target
```

The 0x7F is a constant so the only number that changes based off input is the 0x64.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: I suppose you meant "the lower 7 bits and 8-14 bits" (as per the sample code)? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code translates into this VB code:

```
serialBytes(2) = &h64 And &h7F
serialBytes(3) = (&h64 >> 7) And &h7F
```

If the hex value `64` is actually a variable input, just replace `&h64` with the input variable. If the input is an integer, you have to cast the results to byte, though:

```
serialBytes(2) = CType(value And &H7F, Byte)
serialBytes(3) = CType((value >> 7) And &H7F, Byte)
```

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET has no bit shift operators, but does have the bitwise operator And:

```
set bits1to7  = value And &H007F
set bits8to14 = value And &H3F80
```

**Edit:**

VB.NET does have bit shift operators (my bad) since .NET Framework 1.1, so the more systematic approach is indeed also possible:

```
set bits1to7  = value And &H7F
set bits8to14 = (value >> 7) And &H7F
```

Comment: Yes, VB has bit shift operators: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d9yb87a.aspx